# redefining format style when initializing tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

this is what my tinymce looks like before i adding tinymce init code

[image]

```
            tinymce.init({
              selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your html
              toolbar: "styleselect",
              style_formats: [
                {title: 'main title', inline: 'span', styles: {'text-decoration':'underline','text-decoration-color':'#f00', color: '#000','font-size': '26px','font-weight' : '700', 'display': 'inline-block', 'margin-bottom': '55px','text-align':'center','width':'100%'}},
                {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Cowanbanga', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                {title: 'Table styles'},
                {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
              ]
            });
```

and this is what it looks like after the above code:

[image]

What can I do to still retain style_formats without losing all the interface buttons. I ned them to stay/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did there was - you redefined toolbar property, which by default is something like: `undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent`, with just a single `styleselect`. Consider inserting `styleselect` into the default value instead.

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your html
  toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent",
  style_formats: [
 {title: 'main title', inline: 'span', styles: {'text-decoration':'underline','text-decoration-color':'#f00', color: '#000','font-size': '26px','font-weight' : '700', 'display': 'inline-block', 'margin-bottom': '55px','text-align':'center','width':'100%'}},
 {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
 {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
 {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
 {title: 'Cowanbanga', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
 {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
 {title: 'Table styles'},
 {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.5.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

You can find the list of all possible buttons and other controls [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#toolbarcontrols).